# How to read VFS attributes in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vfs

I have some question.

I try to read some VFS attributes, for example s_magic value in struct super_block.
but I cant read s_magic.

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char boot[1024];
    struct super_block sb;
    fd = open("/dev/fd", O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, boot, 1024);
    read(fd, &sb, sizeof(struct super_block);
    printf("%x\n", sb.s_magic);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
 }
```

so, This code does't work with some error.
In this error, storage size of ‘sb’ isn’t known and invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct super_block’

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `linux/fs.h` does not contain `super_block` declaration. That's because you want to include `linux/fs.h` from Linux **kernel** but actually include `linux/fs.h` from Linux **userspace**. Supply `-I <include path>` option to gcc like this

```
gcc -I /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include
```

**BUT!**

You will get a million of errors because you can't just include kernel headers in your userspace program - you don't have all type and struct definitions.

> The kernel headers are not written with user space in mind, and they
>   can change at any time. The proper way for user-space applications to
>   interface with the kernel is by way of the C library, which provides
>   its own structures and, when necessary, translates them into whatever
>   the current kernel expects. This separation helps to keep user-space
>   programs from breaking when the kernel changes.

(source http://lwn.net/Articles/113349/)

So you have to revise your code.

P.S. I've given you and explanation why your code is not working, but I don't know how you can read super_block in userspace. You better ask another question regarding filesystem superblock API.